# Could a foreign key be a candidate key in the same table?

Tags: mysql, database

I'll try to explain the situation through an example:

I've 2 tables, A and B, in "one to many" relationship between them, B is identified by a single key (pk_B), A is identified by a couple of keys (pk_A1 and pk_A2). So we have two tables:

```
B(pk_B, attr1, attr2, attr3);

A(pk_A1, pk_A2, attr1, attr2, fk_B);
```

For some reasons, fk_B in the A table can be part of the couple of primary keys, so the primary key is

```
pk_A1 + pk_A2 + fk_B.
```

Can it be possible?
I'm sorry if I was too generic. If you want I can try to be more clear explaining the situation with a concrete example.

UPDATE:

EXAMPLE

I've two tables, "Room" and "Area", in a "one to many" relationship (1 room, N areas; 1 area, 1 room). Room is the interior environment of a building, delimited by walls; Area is simply a portion of space. 
Room is identified by a single primary key (Room_ID); Area is identify by a couple of keys: coordinate_X + coordinate_Y. 
To make more concrete example, I add a third table that I call "Object", identified by an ID. An object can be placed in N areas, in an area I could place a single object. So we have three tables:

```
Room (Room_ID, temperature, capacity)

Area(coordinate_X, coordinate_Y, dimension, FK_Room_ID, FK_Object_ID)

Object(Object_ID, name, weight, size)
```

Now, if you think a moment, we have N areas, each area can be identified by the coordinates X & Y, but if we said that in each area can have an object, if I place an object in an area doesn't mean that all the rooms with a certain area have placed an object, and this is not good; because I need to differentiate the area X=1 & Y=1 in the room A and the area X=1 & Y=1 in the room B. So I have to do a primary key consists of three attributes: X coordinate + Y coordinate + Room ID (So, when I will add an object to an area, I need to specify the X coordinate, the Y coordinate and the room where I wanna put the object).

Comment: What are the datatypes and constraints on pk_A1, pk_2 and fk_B?  As far as I know, you can make a composite primary key containing all 3 columns as long as they are unique and non-null.

Comment: Exactly. If you want I update my question with a more concrete example.

Comment: I'm interested to know what error message it gives when you try to include all 3 in the primary key.

Comment: I updated my question with a more concrete and real example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others stated, this is possible. However, I'll add my $0.02.

According to what you said, If `pk_A1` and `pk_A2` already uniquely identify A, why would you add a 3rd column to be part of the primary key? Personally, I don't see any advantage of doing this.

Moreover, suppose there's a 1-to-many relationship between C and A and A's primary keys will be foreign keys in C. By the book, C would have to "inherit" `pk_A1`, `pk_A2` and `fk_B` from A. By not the book, it's also possible to declare C to reference only `pk_A1` and `pk_A2`, leaving `fk_B` once more pointless. Also remember that, when joining A and C, your joins will get unnecessarily longer.

That's why we usually pick the shortest primary key from the set of candidate keys for a table.

Remember that all I said is based on your statement that `(pk_A1, pk_A2)` alone can be primary key.

Comment: I updated my question with a more concrete and real example.

Comment: I see, but in this case what you previously stated `(that pk_A1 and pk_A2 alone)` could be primary key is false and you second that in your edit: `because I need to differentiate the area X=1 & Y=1 in the room A and the area X=1 & Y=1 in the room B`. You answered your question by yourself :-) In this scenario, the primary key might really be `(pk_A1, pk_A2, attr1, attr2, fk_B);`

Comment: Yeah, your answer is also right, but I don't really need to take all the attributes of the table as a primary key, I think that X_coordinate, Y_coordinate and Room_ID could specify a precise and unique portion of the area in a room, or am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct. It was a ctrl+c + ctrl+v issue :-) It seems I can no longer fix my comment, probably because you replied to it. The primary key should be `(pk_A1, pk_A2, fk_B)`.

Comment: Okay, we cleared all doubts, thank you so much for the help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A foreign key can be to another key in the same time. Consider for example a 'parent' key in a tree, or a Paypal IPN transaction table come to think of it. I have implemented several examples such as these.

Comment: I updated my question with a more concrete and real example.

Comment: The answer is still 'yes'.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, the following code executes successfully.  Please specify the error message you are getting that prevents you from adding the primary key?

```
create table Room (
    Room_ID int primary key,
    temperature numeric(5,2),
    capacity int
)

create table Obj (
    Obj_ID int primary key,
    name varchar(max),
    obj_weight numeric(10,2),
    obj_size numeric(10,2)
)

create table Area (
    coordinate_X int,
    coordinate_Y int,
    dimension int,
    FK_Room_ID int,
    FK_Obj_ID int,
    primary key (coordinate_x, coordinate_Y, FK_Room_ID),
    foreign key (FK_Room_ID) references Room (Room_ID),
    foreign key (FK_Obj_ID) references Obj (Obj_ID)
)
```

(edited for MySql)

Comment: I've not created the tables yet, mine is just a logical question. I asked just to know if it's possible and correct, or wrong and to be avoided. Thank you anyway for the code, I'll need it for later. I just wanted to make you think a bit with my example.

Comment: Okay from the wording in your question, I thought you meant that you were getting an error.  Yes it is possible, and not an uncommon practice.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Although you can have the coordinate x, y and room_id combination as a primary key, think about the changes you may have to make when you remodel that room and its coordinate changes. It is advisable for primary keys to not change.

Also, room

I recommend the following design:

```
-- contains information about just the room
create table room (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  capacity int,
  temperature_c int
  primary key (id)
);

-- contains information about area
create table area (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  nickname varchar(100), -- e.g. dresser by bed
  coordinate_x int,
  coordinate_y int,
  dimension_m2 int,
  primary key (id)
);

-- gives the ability to manage one room and many areas; 
-- or even many rooms and many areas (flexible for future needs)
create table room_area (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  room_id int not null,
  area_id int not null,
  primary key (id),
  constraint uk_room_area_ids unique key (room_id, area_id)
);

-- master table of objects
create table object (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(100),
  weight_kg int,
  size_m2 int,
  primary key (id)
);

-- define which object goes in what area of what room
create table room_area_object (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  object_id int not null,
  room_area_id int not null,
  quantity int,
  primary key (id),
  constraint uk_room_area_object_ids unique key (room_area_id, object_id)
);
```

This design allows some more flexibility in defining room, area and object master tables and bringing their particular specialties together in a junction table. If you have 2 exactly same beds, they can go in object table as a single entry but with quantity = 2. They can then be allocated to room bedroom1 and area sleeping-area.

Comment: Excellent alternative solution, although more contorted, with more relationships. Thank you so much, I will keep in mind :-)